# Structure my database to make search queries fast

Tags: sql-server, database-design

- My computer has 64 cores
- Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools 16.0.62007.23150 installed
- I do have 500 Mb/s SSD for the moment

One initial question: Which SQL version would be best for 64 cores?

I am new to SQL databases and have understood that it is important how you structure the database so it will go faster later to search and extract the information needed (queries).

**All data will be used only for CPU calculations and will not be displayed visually in any dataGridView, report etc. The data will be used for artificial intelligence/random forest.**

I believe I have also understood that using data types that take up less memory is good for speed later on also, like using a `smallint` instead of an `int` if it will work with a `smallint` etc.

I like to ask if my structure that I am thinking of is well designed in order to extract information later or if I should do this a bit differently. The database will add stock symbol data and as I notice this database will be extremely big which is the purpose of this question.

**This is the whole structure that I have in mind (Example comes after explanation):**

1. I will use 4 columns. (DateTime|Symbol|FeatureNr|Value)
2. DateTime has format down to the minute: `201012051545`
3. Symbol and FeatureNr has `smallint`. For example: MSFT = 1, IBM = 2, AAPL = 3. So as you see. Instead of using strings in the columns, I have put `smallint` that represent those symbols/featureNr. This so search Queries goes faster later.
4. The database will for example have 50 symbols where each symbol has 5000 features.
5. The database will have 15 years of data.

**Now I have a few big questions:**

If we just filling this database with data for 1 symbol. It will be this many rows in the database:

1440 minutes(1 day) * 365 days * 15 years * 5000 features = 39,420,000,000

**Question 1:**

39,420,000,000 rows in a database seems like a lot or is this no problem?

**Question 2:**

The above was just for 1 symbol. Now I had 50 symbols which would mean:

39,420,000,000 * 50 = 1,971,000,000,000 rows.

I don't know what to say about this. Is this to many rows or is it okay? Should I have 1 database per symbol for example and not all 50 symbols in one database?

**Question 3:**

**Not looking** at how many rows it is in the database. Do you think the database is well structured for fast search queries. What I ALWAYS will search for every time is this (This will later return 5000 lines(features). Notice that I search for one symbol **ONLY** and a specific datetime.

I will always do this exact search, and vever any other type of search, if you have any idea how I should best structure the database with those 50 stock symbols.

I will need all 5000 rows/features, where each row is a feature that needs to be fed to the random forest algorithm. This means that each symbol and update `201012051546` have 5000 features/values.

**As in Question 2. Should I have one table per symbol. Will this result in faster searches for example?**

(symbol = 2, smalldatetime = 201012051546) where I want to return the featureNr and value which would be the below lines: **(I will ALWAYS ONLY do this exact search)**

```
201012051546 | 2 | 1 | 76.123456789
201012051546 | 2 | 2 | 76.123456789
201012051546 | 2 | 3 | 76.123456789
```

**Question 4:**

Wouldn't it be the most optimal to have 1 table for each symbol and datetime?

In other words: 1 table for **symbol = 2 and smalldatetime 1546** which holds 5000 rows of features and then do this for each symbol and datetime?

This will result in 7,884,000 tables per symbol.

Or is this not good in any other way? **Notice here that I will need to in a loop later retrieve all features(5000 per table) from all those tables(7,884,000 tables) which is very important that it goes as fast as possible**. I know it might be difficult to know but how long time **approx**: could a process like this with my structure take with a 64 core computer?

1440 minutes(1 day) * 365 days * 15 years = 7,884,000 tables per symbol

---

**My idea for the database/table structure:**

```
smalldatetime | symbol (smallint) | featureNr (smallint) | value (float(53))

201012051545 | 1 | 1 | 65.123456789
201012051546 | 1 | 1 | 66.123456789
201012051547 | 1 | 1 | 67.123456789
201012051545 | 1 | 2 | 65.123456789
201012051546 | 1 | 2 | 66.123456789
201012051547 | 1 | 2 | 67.123456789
201012051545 | 1 | 3 | 65.123456789
201012051546 | 1 | 3 | 66.123456789
201012051547 | 1 | 3 | 67.123456789

201012051545 | 2 | 1 | 75.123456789
201012051546 | 2 | 1 | 76.123456789
201012051547 | 2 | 1 | 77.123456789
201012051545 | 2 | 2 | 75.123456789
201012051546 | 2 | 2 | 76.123456789
201012051547 | 2 | 2 | 77.123456789
201012051545 | 2 | 3 | 75.123456789
201012051546 | 2 | 3 | 76.123456789
201012051547 | 2 | 3 | 77.123456789

201012051545 | 3 | 1 | 85.123456789
201012051546 | 3 | 1 | 86.123456789
201012051547 | 3 | 1 | 87.123456789
201012051545 | 3 | 2 | 85.123456789
201012051546 | 3 | 2 | 86.123456789
201012051547 | 3 | 2 | 87.123456789
201012051545 | 3 | 3 | 85.123456789
201012051546 | 3 | 3 | 86.123456789
201012051547 | 3 | 3 | 87.123456789
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

As answered in the comments, unless you are hitting this table with a LOT of reads, the number of cores is probably less important:

> Your first question is answered in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/compute-capacity-limits-by-edition-of-sql-server); you will need Enterprise Edition to use more than 24 cores. With a unique clustered index on the natural key (datetime, symbol, feature) I would expect millisecond response time with a single table using a single core. Manageability of a 50TB table is another matter. - [Dan Guzman](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/44434/dan-guzman)

> Your proposed workload is not going to be cpu constrained.  As Dan Guzman said the structure appears solid and you can expect great performance out of your specified design and queries on even modest (server grade, for sure, but modest) hardware.  Make sure your disks are as fast as possible. - [Jonathan Fite](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/46773/jonathan-fite)

You don't define the keys explicitly, although you do mention:

> Notice that I search for one symbol ONLY and a specific datetime. I
> will always do this exact search, and Never any other type of search,
> if you have any idéa how I should best structure the database with
> those 50 stock symbols.

So:

1. If you need to know a price as of a point in time for a particular symbol and feature, you only need to store when the price actually changes.  No need to store minute by minute.  In practical terms, this means you will most likely have a lot less than ~7 million rows per symbol.  Even if things did change by the minute, that would only occur while the exchange was open.
2. If the search will always be for a particular symbol, it forms part of the primary key and within the physical structure of SQL Server, it should be the leading column of the clustered index.
3. You are correct that everything else being equal, a small row size will result in faster performance.  However, that shouldn't be the overriding motivation for the selection of a key.  Saving 2-3 bytes per row isn't worth it if it requires additional overhead to query or maintain uniqueness.

I'd say you're close (with a few caveats), so let's start by defining the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Stock
(
  StockSymbol  CHAR(5)      NOT NULL --NYSE is 3, NASDAQ is 4-5
 ,Name         VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_Stock PRIMARY KEY (StockSymbol)
 ,CONSTRAINT AK_Stock UNIQUE (Name)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE StockFeature
(
  StockSymbol  CHAR(5)      NOT NULL
 ,FeatureNbr   SMALLINT     NOT NULL  --I'm assuming this value is understood ahead of time, otherwise consider using a shortname or code
 ,Name         VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL
 ,CONSTRAINT FK_StockFeature_Describes_Stock FOREIGN KEY (StockSymbol) REFERENCES Stock (StockSymbol)
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_StockFeature PRIMARY KEY (StockSymbol, FeatureNbr)
 ,CONSTRAINT AK_StockFeature UNIQUE (StockSymbol, Name)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE StockFeatureValue
(
  StockSymbol  CHAR(5)       NOT NULL
 ,FeatureNbr   SMALLINT      NOT NULL
 ,ValueDtm     DATETIME2(0)  NOT NULL
 ,Value        FLOAT(53)     NOT NULL
 ,CONSTRAINT FK_StockFeatureValue_Measurement_Of_StockFeature FOREIGN KEY (StockSymbol, FeatureNbr) REFERENCES StockFeature (StockSymbol, FeatureNbr)
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_StockFeatureValue PRIMARY KEY (StockSymbol, FeatureNbr, ValueDtm)
)
GO
```

Now if we want the values for all features of a symbol at a given point in time, this query will return data very quickly:

```
SELECT
  SFVal.StockSymbol
 ,SFVal.FeatureNbr
 ,SFVal.Value
FROM
  StockFeatureValue SFVal
WHERE
  SFVal.StockSymbol = 'MSFT'
    AND SFVal.ValueDtm =
      (
        SELECT
          MAX(ValueDtm)
        FROM
          StockFeatureValue 
        WHERE
          StockSymbol = SFVal.StockSymbol
            AND FeatureNbr = SFVal.FeatureNbr
            AND ValueDtm <= '2010-12-05 15:45:00'  --Or whatever
      )
```

The reason this will work is the primary key is defined as `(StockSymbol, FeatureNbr, ValueDtm)`.  Order is important here, as SQL Server will store the rows (for the most part) sorted according to those values.  Which means to return the necessary data, the database has to read at most 1 page per feature.  In practical terms this is nothing.

We could use a `SMALLINT` for `StockSymbol` but that would require an additional query to `Stock` to retrieve the necessary value, which isn't the end of the world but not really worth it for 3 bytes/row.

**One observation** - in your sample data `Value` doesn't vary across features.  I don't know if this is an artifact of how you generated the data, but if `Value` does not change according to `FeatureNbr` then you have a normalization error and the primary key should be `(StockSymbol, ValueDtm)` with the feature information stored elsewhere.

My answer to a similar question may also be of benefit:
[MySQL DB design for very long growing row size](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/272986/mysql-db-design-for-very-long-growing-row-size/273046#273046)

Addressing a comment:

> I understand, so it is better to use your example. I really need to
> learn all that code you did for the 3 tables, I am looking at it but
> are not exactly sure how everything links.(All the rows where
> CONSTRAINT is used. I have a problem to understand) If I understand
> you have linked them somehow so search queries will work in an
> efficient way when you execute that code for '2010-12-05 15:45:00'

Those are foreign key constraints.  They do two things:

1. Keep invalid values out of your database
2. Inform the database engine of the relation between the tables so better query plans can be generated

Another thing I want to clarify, if our actual data is this:

```
StockSymbol | FeatureNbr    | ValueDtm              | Value
'MSFT'      | 1             | '2015-01-01 00:01:00' | 1.000
'MSFT'      | 1             | '2015-01-01 00:02:00' | 1.000
'MSFT'      | 1             | '2015-01-01 00:03:00' | 1.000
'MSFT'      | 1             | '2015-01-01 00:04:00' | 1.100
'MSFT'      | 1             | '2015-01-01 00:05:00' | 1.100
'MSFT'      | 1             | '2015-01-01 00:06:00' | 1.100
'MSFT'      | 1             | '2015-01-01 00:07:00' | 1.100
'MSFT'      | 1             | '2015-01-01 00:08:00' | 1.100
'MSFT'      | 1             | '2015-01-01 00:09:00' | 1.201
'MSFT'      | 1             | '2015-01-01 00:10:00' | 1.100
'MSFT'      | 2             | '2015-01-01 00:01:00' | 0.253
'MSFT'      | 2             | '2015-01-01 00:02:00' | 0.253
'MSFT'      | 2             | '2015-01-01 00:03:00' | 0.253
'MSFT'      | 2             | '2015-01-01 00:04:00' | 0.253
'MSFT'      | 2             | '2015-01-01 00:05:00' | 0.253
'MSFT'      | 2             | '2015-01-01 00:06:00' | 0.561
'MSFT'      | 2             | '2015-01-01 00:07:00' | 0.561
'MSFT'      | 2             | '2015-01-01 00:08:00' | 0.561
'MSFT'      | 2             | '2015-01-01 00:09:00' | 0.561
'MSFT'      | 2             | '2015-01-01 00:10:00' | 0.561
'MSFT'      | 3             | '2015-01-01 00:01:00' | 6.942
'MSFT'      | 3             | '2015-01-01 00:02:00' | 6.942
'MSFT'      | 3             | '2015-01-01 00:03:00' | 6.942
'MSFT'      | 3             | '2015-01-01 00:04:00' | 6.942
'MSFT'      | 3             | '2015-01-01 00:05:00' | 6.942
'MSFT'      | 3             | '2015-01-01 00:06:00' | 6.942
'MSFT'      | 3             | '2015-01-01 00:07:00' | 6.942
'MSFT'      | 3             | '2015-01-01 00:08:00' | 6.942
'MSFT'      | 3             | '2015-01-01 00:09:00' | 6.942
'MSFT'      | 3             | '2015-01-01 00:10:00' | 6.942
```

We would only need seven rows to represent the same amount of data:

```
StockSymbol | FeatureNbr    | ValueDtm              | Value
'MSFT'      | 1             | '2015-01-01 00:01:00' | 1.000
'MSFT'      | 1             | '2015-01-01 00:04:00' | 1.100
'MSFT'      | 1             | '2015-01-01 00:09:00' | 1.201
'MSFT'      | 1             | '2015-01-01 00:10:00' | 1.100
'MSFT'      | 2             | '2015-01-01 00:01:00' | 0.253
'MSFT'      | 2             | '2015-01-01 00:06:00' | 0.561
'MSFT'      | 3             | '2015-01-01 00:01:00' | 6.942
```

And this is the power of the data model.  We don't have to store every minute of data to return the correct result.  And we can return that result quickly because the clustered index allows us to find the necessary rows without reading large chunks of the table.

Addressing additional comments:

> I know this is a beginner question. But I don't really understand why
> 3 tables are used. Why couldn't we just use one table and put
> everything in that table? When using 3 tables. StockSymbol, FeatureNbr
> and Name exists in 2-3 tables. Doesn't this mean that the database
> will take up more memory as those becomes duplicates? I also wonder
> why Name is a column. StockSymbol should be the name of the symbol?

This is a result of normalization.  We normalize the data to ensure the data contained within is consistent with our understanding.  So yes, we *could* store the data in a single table, but we would have no way of guaranteeing the data is consistent.

The `Stock` table guarantees that only valid stock symbols are inserted into `StockFeature`, which guarantees that only valid stock symbols/features are inserted into our final table.

If I Google MSFT, it shows 'MSFT - Microsoft Corporation'.  'Microsoft Corporation' is the `Name` of the `Stock`.  This is data the belongs to the `Stock` alone - we would not store it anywhere else.

There's not a lot of *good* information on database normalization (a lot varies between okay and really bad), but if you don't mind digging into some heavy reading you can start with [EF Codd's work](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/%7Ezives/03f/cis550/codd.pdf) and then maybe move on to one of CJ Date's books, although I find them lacking in some regards (his treatment of time-dependent data is... bad).

> You mentioned: this means you will most likely have a lot less than ~7
> million rows per symbol Notice that it would be: 39,420,000,000 rows
> per symbol in one table as I calculated in my original post. Is this a
> problem for this search algorithm to have so many rows in one table?

See the above example for why you would most likely have far less than ~39 billion rows.  You would only have that many rows if each feature changed values every minute.  And even if this was the case (it most likely isn't), the above solution will still work as the right clustered index will allow the database to find the necessary pages quickly.

The search algorithm in this case is a B-Tree, and the overall size of the table generally will not impact individual lookups.  The total row size impacts maintenance, aggregation, and queries that cannot utilize an efficient indexing strategy, so we don't want to make things bigger than they have to be.

Comment: bbaird thank you, this is very interesting what you did. I understand the concept but perheps only about 50% of the code since I have just begun with SQL. I will use your example until I understand how you have done it. My `sample data values`, I have just put anything there in my example. They will vary all the time in reality.

Comment: Without understanding all your example yet. I might wonder this. What if I created one table for each symbol and datetime. For example MSFT,201012051546 and MSFT,201012051547 would mean 2 separate tables where we already know the symbol and datetime and by this doesn't need to put that information in any columns. Then each table have all 5000 features where I always want to return all of them? Wouldn't this be very effective to do it like this as this will be the only functionality that I am after?

Comment: @coding - No, splitting things into different tables won't do anything here as the values by Symbol/feature are already co-located.  So it's better use to let the database locate the rows instead of trying to split the data into separate tables.  I'll try to set up the fiddle with some sample data so you can see how things fit together.

Comment: I understand, so it is better to use your example. I really need to learn all that code you did for the 3 tables, I am looking at it but are not exactly sure how everything links.(All the rows where `CONSTRAINT` is used. I have a problem to understand) If I understand you have linked them somehow so search queries will work in an efficient way when you execute that code for `'2010-12-05 15:45:00'`?

Comment: @coding See comment, I've also added an example about how to best store the data.  SQLFiddle is acting goofy, I'll try to put that together later today.

Comment: thank you, I will study your code until I understand it. I try to learn about those `constraints` to understand how this really works. Yes your example made me understand now how you mean to not save every 1-minute data to save both harddisk space and make searches faster in the table. Yes no problem ofcourse.

Comment: bbaird I know this is a beginner question. But I don't really understand why 3 tables are used.
Why couldn't we just use one table and put everything in that table?
When using 3 tables. `StockSymbol`, `FeatureNbr` and `Name` exists in 2-3 tables. 
Doesn't this mean that the database will take up more memory as those becomes duplicates?
I also wonder why `Name` is a column. `StockSymbol` should be the name of the symbol?

Comment: You mentioned: `this means you will most likely have a lot less than ~7 million rows per symbol` Notice that it would be: `39,420,000,000 rows per symbol` in one table as I calculated in my original post. Is this a problem/will be very slow, for this search algorithm to have so many rows in one table?

Comment: @coding Please see updated answer.

Comment: That is amazing bbaird, now I really understand better. I have studied every syntax last 5 hours and now I start to understand this better/quite good to start doing some tests. Now I understand why the 3 tables were used then. It sorted out some question marks so it makes sense now. Your idéa with `<=` in `AND ValueDtm <= 2010-12-05 15:45:00` solved a complete other problem also. That was really good to reach the last updated value like that. I think I am good to go and start trying out this. Thank you for all this help! It was very very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

> I am new to SQL databases and have understood that it is important how
> you structure the database so it will go faster later to search and
> extract the information needed(Queries).

Excellent thinking.

`Smallint` can be replace by `Tinyint`.

Your table will be very frequently Inserted i.e per minute Insert.
There will be no update or Delete.

The table will be also queried but not as frequently as it will be inserted.

Is it correct ?

You have to determine `Clustered Index` at this stage.This is one important factor for both `Insert/Select`.

Choice 1 : Symbol+smalldatetime

They are Selective enough,Ever increasing,data type is ok.

Will you insert back date data ?

Choice 2 : Create another column which is identity.Create this as Clsutered Index.

Insert performance is guranteed to improve.
In this case you have to Create `Symbol+smalldatetime` as `NonClustered Index`.

Best will be creeate dummy data and test both Choice.

> I will ALWAYS ONLY do this exact search

This is wrong assumption.you have to think about Scalability of database,future requirement etc.

Today it is 50 symbol, t'row it can be 55,65.. and so on.

It appear that you will have to consider `Partition` in which ever way you design your database.

Store data for all Symbol in one 1 Table for 1 year.
Partition your table year wise.
In this case you hv to Add one column Year (Tinyint).

Also pass year as paramter whenever you query it (For fasterter retreival).

> Notice here that I will need to in a loop later retreive all
> features(5000) from all those tables(

To retreive all features(5000) you do not need to LOOP.

Comment: `Store data for all Symbol in one 1 Table for 1 year` I am thinking in those terms. I am still not sure/convinced that if I had 50 symbols, I would have about 1,971,000,000,000 rows. of data in one table. Assume that `clustered index` was `Symbol+smalldatetime` will search queries be as fast as if I had a table with let us say only 100 Million rows? What if the table was 10 Billion rows etc? I think I will only need to use `smalldatetime` as a clustered index as it is increasing and I would use one table per symbol. So a symbol column would then not be needed.

Comment: I think I will query the table more often then it is inserted because I will do enormous amounts of test calculations against that data in the table.

Comment: @coding, is smalldatetime unique ?

Comment: Yes smalldatetime will always be unique. Like `2010102248`, `2010102249`, `2010102247`, `2010102245`, `2010102255`. Would that work as `clustered index`. Notice that I inserted them in the wrong order there but if I understand SQL will understand that and do efficient queries anyway even that they were inserted in the wrong order?

Comment: @coding,Clustered Index phyically sort the data in partcular manner, so no issue, for Select.Still wrong order implies that SmallDatetime is not ever increasing,Insert performance may be hurt .Sql Optimizer will spend time to search for  exact data pages where it will want to insert the data,there may be minor page split or no page split,because each row is of fix size.

Comment: I see, that was good then. I think its okay since 99% of the time the data will come in the correct order. Only once in a while the data/`smalldatetime` will come in the wrong order. But then it would work anyway. I still really wonder about a table with `1,971,000,000,000 rows` vs a table with for example `100 million rows` only. Will not the 100 million rows table be much faster using queries. Let us assume that we have `Symbol and smalldatetime` as `clustered index` ? It is a big question, if its faster to use 1 table for each year for example rather then all 15 years of data in one table?

Comment: Symbol + smalldatetime (4+4=8 bytes) as clustered index,Optimizer has one good reason to prefer this as it is not expensive at all,I will Store data for all symbol in one table, then do Partition year wise.This way I have to query only one table, whatever be the query requirement.

Comment: That is good to know then. I should use Partition year wise. How much slower do you think a 1,971,000,000,000 rows vs  a 100 million rows table is with the same clustered index?

Answer (score -1):

> 39,420,000,000 rows in a database seems like alot or is this no problem?

Definitely possible, but it's something to worry about.  Since

> I will need all those 5000 rows/features. Where each row is a feature that needs to be fed to the random forest algorithm

you might store it in a table like:

```
 (DateTime|Symbol|Features)
```

where Features is as `varchar(max)` column containing the 5000 features in JSON format, or as `varbinary(max)` stored using a format that can be read and written by your ML models, or [COMPRESS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/compress-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)ed (GZIP) JSON.

That will reduce the row count to 7.8M/symbol.

And if you always search for a single (DateTime,Symbol), you would use a clustered index on those two columns.  And you would probably partition by year so you easilly remove old years in the future.  EG

```
create partition function pf_DateTime(bigint)
   as range right for values
   (
      201000000000,
      201100000000,
      201200000000,
      201300000000,
      201400000000,
      201500000000,
      201600000000,
      201700000000,
      201800000000,
      201900000000,
      202000000000,
      202100000000,
      202200000000,
      202300000000
   )

create partition scheme ps_DateTime
  as partition pf_DateTime all to ([Primary])

create table StockFeatures
(
  Symbol int,
  DateTime bigint,
  Features varchar(max),
  primary key (Symbol,DateTime)
) on ps_DateTime(DateTime)
  with (data_compression=page)
```

You might also want to use a `datetime2(0)` for the DateTime instead of a nummber.

If you store the features as JSON you can either parse the JSON on the client, or have SQL Server do it for you using the [OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function, eg

```
 select Symbol, DateTime, f.[key] FeatureNr, f.Value
 from StockFeatures 
 cross apply openjson(Features) f
 where Symbol = @s 
   and DateTime = @t
```

If you compressed the data and stored in `varbinary(max)` that would be

```
 select Symbol, DateTime, f.[key] FeatureNr, f.Value
 from StockFeatures 
 cross apply openjson(decompress(Features)) f
 where Symbol = @s 
   and DateTime = @t
```

Comment: David, having worked with databases set up like this - they are inflexible and painful to work with.  SQL Server can handle this type of data easily with the right clustered index and pruning of unnecessary values.  I have used SQL Server to run circles around other platforms (Netezza, Teradata) by doing just that.

Comment: But this is a very specific use case,  and storing and retrieving a single blob will probably be significantly cheaper than 5000 rows.  The alternate design is essentially EAV, which has it's own issues.