# How to write search query to retrevie the rows with biggest DateTime <= 2010102248 in SQL

Tags: sql-server, query, c#

I am creating a table and now trying to create my first Search Query.

1. I have created the table successfully like this:

   ```
    CREATE TABLE testTable
    (
      DateTime INT    NOT NULL, /*yyyyddhhmm, 2010102345*/
      FeatureNbr      SMALLINT  NOT NULL,
      Val FLOAT(53)   NOT NULL
    );
   ```
2. I have successfully inserted values to the table like this:

   ```
    INSERT INTO testTable(DateTime, FeatureNbr, Val) VALUES(2010102245, 0, 12.56789);
    INSERT INTO testTable(DateTime, FeatureNbr, Val) VALUES(2010102245, 1, 13.56789);
    INSERT INTO testTable(DateTime, FeatureNbr, Val) VALUES(2010102245, 2, 14.56789);

    INSERT INTO testTable(DateTime, FeatureNbr, Val) VALUES(2010102246, 0, 15.56789);
    INSERT INTO testTable(DateTime, FeatureNbr, Val) VALUES(2010102246, 1, 16.56789);
    INSERT INTO testTable(DateTime, FeatureNbr, Val) VALUES(2010102246, 2, 17.56789);

    INSERT INTO testTable(DateTime, FeatureNbr, Val) VALUES(2010102247, 0, 18.56789);
    INSERT INTO testTable(DateTime, FeatureNbr, Val) VALUES(2010102247, 1, 19.56789);
   ```
3. Now I have a little problem and questions. I am trying to create a search query to retreive `ALL` `FeatureNbrm,Val,DateTime` where the `biggest datetime` is found `<= 2010102248` for each of the three features. The lines that should be retrevied would then be the below 3 lines, - for ALL the three features which are: 0,1,2 (We don't know how many features it is. We just want ALL of them/rows with the biggest datetime)

```
2010102246, 2, 17.56789  
2010102247, 0, 18.56789  
2010102247, 1, 19.56789
```

**But I only retrieve those lines in this format for the features: 0 and 1**

```
2, 2010102246, 17.56789 <-- is missing
0, 2010102247, 18.56789
1, 2010102247, 19.56789
```

The code I use is the below but I don't understand how I should write this correctly?

```
SELECT FeatureNbr, DateTime, Val
FROM
  testTable
WHERE
     testTable.DateTime=
      (
        SELECT
          MAX(DateTime)
        FROM
          testTable 
        WHERE
          DateTime <= 2010102248
      )
```

Comment: Is this date format correct? yyyyddhhmm There are years and days and no months?

Comment: And this is an excellent demonstration of why you should use date (or related) datatypes to store temporal values. And why you should ALWAYS store 4 digit years - read the comments about similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64220853/sql-date-conversion-19s-instead-of-20s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure your subquery is *correlated* with the main query, so you are getting the max timestamp for each feature:

```
SELECT
  test.FeatureNbr,
  test.DateTime,
  test.Val
FROM
  testTable test
WHERE
  DateTime =
    (
      SELECT
        MAX(DateTime)
      FROM
        testTable
      WHERE
        FeatureNbr = test.FeatureNbr  --This is what you are missing
          AND DateTime <= '2020-10-06 12:55:00' --Or whatever
    )
```

See this DB Fiddle:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a57b5d632f53a973a6225718e2baea3a

A few other points:

1. Always store date/time values as `DATETIME2` in SQL Server.  Otherwise you can end up with invalid date/time combinations and won't be able to use the native date functions without first converting.
2. You need to make sure your primary key is defined - the right clustered index (in this example `(FeatureNbr,Datetime)`) is critical - it will allow the query to complete reading the table once and without sorts.
3. This was addressed in my answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/276530/212533), but I know you are starting out so it might not have been apparent due to the length.
4. Should also be mentioned that with the proper clustered index, SQL Server will recognize the queries provided by nbk and Andy Mallon (which are identical since a CTE is just another way of writing the same thing) to be equivalent to the above query - they will produce the exact same query plan and return the exact same result.  It's just more code.

To address your comment:

> Yes I begin to understand it a bit better but its so new. I know C#
> for 10 years but this is alot of "nesting" like it feels.
> After WHERE there should be a condition. You put: WHERE DateTime = (...). Is this  some kind of "temp table" that is happening here, where you later:
> FeatureNbr = test.FeatureNbr? I also wonder if it will be correct to
> put this condition against DateTime like this? WHERE FeatureNbr =
> test.FeatureNbr AND DayTime <= 2010102248 (I know the datetime format
> got wrong here but it will work for the example as an integer)

Making the transition from object oriented/traditional programming to database development is a hard one as you're used to specifying exactly HOW things are done.  SQL is a declarative language, we specify *what* we want and allow the database engine to determine the optimal plan.

So the "nesting" here is just specifying that the `Datetime` must equal the max `Datetime` less than or equal to the specified value *for each* `FeatureNbr`.  The query engine then looks at the table, the indexes, the column statistics, and decides the best way to fulfill that query.  If you have a good data model, you rarely have to tune queries.

You will probably want to start to familiarize yourself with how to read query/execution plans and the specific operators.  Then you can experiment with how the engine actually fulfills the requests, how your clustered index influences the plan, etc.

If you were to generate query plans for three of the answers (nbk's, Andy's, and my own) they would be *identical* with the right clustered index.  The answer that uses `ROW_NUMBER()` forces a sort, which is instructive in its own way.

Additional comment:

> If I understand, it doesn't matter in what order you write this(When
> you combine columns): CONSTRAINT PK_testTable PRIMARY KEY
> (FeatureNbr,DateTime) it could be written like this also: CONSTRAINT
> PK_testTable PRIMARY KEY (DateTime,FeatureNbr)

So this brings up a *very important* concept for the physical implementation of tables in SQL Server, which is the rows are stored (more or less) in the *order* according to the position of the rows specified during the creation of the clustered index.

So: `(FeatureNbr,Datetime)` sorts first by `FeatureNbr` (let's call this option 1) while `(Datetime,FeatureNbr)` sorts first by `Datetime` (option 2).

If we do a query that looks for one row and one row only (say, `FeatureNbr = 2 AND Datetime = '2020-10-06 10:33:00'`), both indexes will perform identically.  But if we do a query that has to look across ranges of `Datetime` for a given `FeatureNbr`, option 1 would allow the clustered index to be utilized, option 2 would result in a table scan.  This is because for option 1 the engine knows all values for a `FeatureNbr` will be on the same page(s) (more or less), but for option 2 the relevant rows could be stored anywhere in the table.

For this reason, a date or datetime column should be the last row in an index as a general rule (in databases there are always exceptions).

Comment: Yes I begin to understand it a bit better but its so new. I know C# for 10 years 
but this is alot of "nesting" like it feels. After `WHERE` there should be a condition. You put: `WHERE DateTime = (...)`. Is this some kind of "temp table" that is happening here, where you later: `FeatureNbr = test.FeatureNbr`? I also wonder if it will be correct to put this condition against DateTime like this? `WHERE FeatureNbr = test.FeatureNbr AND DayTime <= 2010102248` (I know the datetime format got wrong here but it will work for the example as an integer)

Comment: `DATETIME2` thank you, that is good to know. I must use this as you mention to prevent conversions later. `FeatureNbr,Datetime` is very good to understand this. I must then use this as primary key.

Comment: @coding see updated answer for response to your comments.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. Yes now it feels better when you said: `transition from object oriented/traditional programming to database development is a hard one` :) It´s true, it feels a bit backwards. But then I understand as you say that the query engine will look for the most optimal plan. That makes sense. It is a good idéa to experiment as you say with different queries and see what happens and the `clustering index` is so important to get correct also.

Comment: If I understand, it doesn't matter in what order you write this(When you combine columns): `CONSTRAINT PK_testTable PRIMARY KEY (FeatureNbr,DateTime)` it could be written like this also: `CONSTRAINT PK_testTable PRIMARY KEY (DateTime,FeatureNbr)` ?

Comment: @coding Explanation is a little too long for the comment section so I've appended to the answer.

Comment: bbaird, now I really understand that concept also. A really good explanation. I would sort it in the same way in C# if I did a function like that also. This makes really sense. Thank you for all help and explanations!

Answer (score 1):

You need some more information, and you can use a INNER JOIN for that purpose

> ```
>  CREATE TABLE testTable
>  (
>    DateTime INT    NOT NULL, /*yyyyddhhmm, 2010102345*/
>    FeatureNbr      SMALLINT  NOT NULL,
>    Val FLOAT(53)   NOT NULL
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO testTable(DateTime, FeatureNbr, Val) VALUES(2010102245, 0, 12.56789);
>  INSERT INTO testTable(DateTime, FeatureNbr, Val) VALUES(2010102245, 1, 13.56789);
>  INSERT INTO testTable(DateTime, FeatureNbr, Val) VALUES(2010102245, 2, 14.56789);
>
>  INSERT INTO testTable(DateTime, FeatureNbr, Val) VALUES(2010102246, 0, 15.56789);
>  INSERT INTO testTable(DateTime, FeatureNbr, Val) VALUES(2010102246, 1, 16.56789);
>  INSERT INTO testTable(DateTime, FeatureNbr, Val) VALUES(2010102246, 2, 17.56789);
>
>  INSERT INTO testTable(DateTime, FeatureNbr, Val) VALUES(2010102247, 0, 18.56789);
>  INSERT INTO testTable(DateTime, FeatureNbr, Val) VALUES(2010102247, 1, 19.56789)
> GO
> ```

8 rows affected

> 

> ```
> SELECT t1.* 
> FROM testTable t1 
> INNER JOIN  (SELECT FeatureNbr,  MAX(DateTime) as maxdatetimel  FROM testTable  
>          WHERE
>           DateTime <= 2010102248 GROUP BY FeatureNbr  ) t2 
> ON t1.[FeatureNbr]= t2.[FeatureNbr] AND t1.DateTime = t2.maxdatetimel
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
>   DateTime | FeatureNbr |      Val
> ---------: | ---------: | -------:
> 2010102246 |          2 | 17.56789
> 2010102247 |          1 | 19.56789
> 2010102247 |          0 | 18.56789
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=902447b76585067387cd9194a244e9a1)*

For an explaination:

The
SELECT FeatureNbr,  MAX(DateTime) as maxdatetimel  FROM testTable
WHERE
DateTime <= 2010102248 GROUP BY FeatureNbr

Returns the latest datetimes for every FeatureNbr

The inner join connect the source table and the new table which contains the latest datetimes.

To identify the correct row of the source table you need 1.FeatureNbr and 2. the correct datetime, else you could find the correct row.

that is how inner join work, you combines two(or more)  tables and in the ON clause you tell the rdms which rows from both tables it should combine to one.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work. But I struggle to understand this logic how this work. Many questions: `SELECT FeatureNbr,  MAX(DayTime) as maxdatetimel` I don't really understand what: `maxdatetimel` really have for information? Then `GROUP BY FeatureNbr` I don't know what this does or why it is needed? What does `t2` mean exactly? Then this logic, I don't understand what really is happening: `ON t1.[FeatureNbr] = t2.[FeatureNbr] AND t1.DayTime = t2.maxdatetimel`

Comment: I am not sure if you could add an explanation for this in the post. It is to many question marks at the same time. Even that I have read about Inner Join here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: sure in added soe more explanation to teh what the query makes and also some short what a join does.

Comment: Thanks I understand a bit better. Still some question marks: 1. `SELECT FeatureNbr,  MAX(DateTime) as maxdatetimel` makes a column named `maxdatetimel` if I understand correctly? 2.`t2` is a "temp table" ? 3. I don't understand why `GROUP BY FeatureNbr` is needed or what it really does? 4. `t1.DateTime = t2.maxdatetimel` doesn't compare the EXACT same information which should be `DateTime`, They have different information this comparison?

Comment: aed 1) yes maxdatetome ios an alias for the maximum of datetime for **every** FeatureNbr , yes t2 us an alias for the tabke that is created with that select ad 3= Max is a aggregation functiona and with out the group you get the maximum of all FeatureNbr, but you want it for every FeatureNbr  4.) that is a misconception, we are searching for the maximum time for every FeatureNbr , which is stored in the column maxdatetime, and now we only want the rows from testTable  that have that time exactly. your buiggest problem is that tables are by nature unsorted, by getting only the max values

Comment: Thank you, now I start to understand this a bit better. I got some things cleared out there so: `maximum time for every FeatureNbr , is stored in the column maxdatetime`. So SQL know can "find" the `DateTime` in that "new made" column: `maxdatetime`. Yes the tables are by nature unsorted. Thank you for this help!

Answer (score 1):

You need the top row for each feature, with the most recent date before a specified date.

You could do this with three very simple queries that are `UNION`ed together:

```
SELECT TOP 1 t.FeatureNbr, t.DateTime, t.Val
FROM dbo.testTable AS t
WHERE t.DateTime <= 2010102248
AND t.FeatureNbr = 0
    UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1 t.FeatureNbr, t.DateTime, t.Val
FROM dbo.testTable AS t
WHERE t.DateTime <= 2010102248
AND t.FeatureNbr = 1
    UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1 t.FeatureNbr, t.DateTime, t.Val
FROM dbo.testTable AS t
WHERE t.DateTime <= 2010102248
AND t.FeatureNbr = 2;
```

If you need to do 300 `FeatureNbr` values, then this format doesn't make sense, and there are some fancier alternatives, but at least for the case where there are always exactly 3 rows, this is the easiest option, and will perform well with a supporting index.

If you need the more robust option, you can get the most recent datetime for each feature in a CTE, then join back to the table to get the full data (with the join limiting which rows are selected.

```
WITH MaxVals AS (
    SELECT t.FeatureNbr, 
           MaxDateTime = MAX(t.DateTime)
    FROM dbo.testTable AS t
    WHERE t.DateTime <= 2010102248
    GROUP BY t.FeatureNbr
    )
SELECT t.FeatureNbr, t.DateTime, t.Val
FROM dbo.testTable AS t
JOIN MaxVals AS mv 
    ON mv.FeatureNbr = t.FeatureNbr 
    AND mv.MaxDateTime = t.DateTime;
```

Comment: The UNION query is not correct. There are no ORDER BY so the returned rows will be arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT DateTime
        ,FeatureNbr
        ,Val
        ,RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY FeatureNbr ORDER BY DateTime DESC) AS rn
    FROM testTable
    WHERE DateTime <= 2010102248
)
SELECT DateTime
    ,FeatureNbr
    ,Val
FROM CTE 
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is properly working.

First, what your subquery returns:

```
SELECT
  MAX(DateTime)
FROM
  testTable 
WHERE
  DateTime <= 2010102248;
```

> ```
> | (No column name) |
> | ---------------: |
> |       2010102247 |
> ```

Applying the returned value:

```
SELECT *
FROM   testTable
WHERE  testTable.DateTime = 2010102247;
```

> ```
>   DateTime | FeatureNbr |      Val
> ---------: | ---------: | -------:
> 2010102247 |          0 | 18.56789
> 2010102247 |          1 | 19.56789
> ```

Because 2010102247 <> 2010102246

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5e9bf01f9a6def9d8389e58adcc5f84a)*

Comment: I am not sure if this will work? I still miss the line for FeatureNbr `2`. This is the line which is missing: `2, 2010102246, 17.56789`. I try to get the lines which meets exactly this criteria: `DateTime <= 2010102248`

Comment: That's not what your query states